# Problem when submitting EditForm when using using Parameter

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-editform

I'm trying to have a Razor component that can function as the create and update page. When I am submitting a EditForm without passing a parameter in the route the submit function is called but when I pass a parameter and fill my editcontext with existing data the submit button just refreshes the page causing the OnInitializedAsync to be triggered again and my changes to be lost.

```
    public partial class PersonalInfo
    {
        private PersonalInfoModel _personalInfo = new PersonalInfoModel();
        private EditContext _editContext;
        private Response _customerResponse;

        [Parameter]
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        public CustomerService CustomerSvc { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        public NavigationManager NavManager { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            _editContext = new EditContext(_personalInfo);

            _customerResponse = await CustomerSvc.GetCustomer(CustomerId ?? 0);

            if (_customerResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                _personalInfo = _customerResponse.Content.Serialize().Deserialize<PersonalInfoModel>();
                _editContext = new EditContext(_personalInfo);
            }
        }

        private async Task Submit()
        {
            int customerId;
            if (_customerResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                customerId = await CustomerSvc.UpdateCustomer(_personalInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                customerId = await CustomerSvc.CreateCustomer(_personalInfo);
            }
     }
```

Razor Page

```
@page "/PersonalInfo/{CustomerId:int?}"
 <EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="@Submit">

 </EditForm>
```

Update:

I trimmed down the razor page to one field and not even a data annotation validator. It still has the same issue.

[image: Razor Page]

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've added to your question that would force a page refresh.  So either `CustomerSvc.UpdateCustomer` is doing it or there's more active code in the process that you aren't showing us.  You inject `NavigationManager`.  Where are you using it?

Comment: I'm using NavigationManager int the submit function after my create or update, but the submit isnt getting hit when the edit context is  populated with existing data. I assume that its forcing a page refresh since OnInitializedAsync is immediately getting hit when I try and submit the new data. I just double checked and there is no javascript acting on the submit button ether.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I even swapped from OnInitializedAsync to OnParametersSetAsync with no result change.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation. For me, the `OnInitializedAsync` function was called twice due to pre-rendering. Once I disabled it, the form worked without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, it's a starting point for you to investigate what's causing your problem.

Here's a single page that does basically what you're doing, with some `Task.Delay` calls to emulate the data gets and some AdLibing.

Test it in your Application to make sure it works.  Then figure out what you're doing that different and causing the problem.

```cs
@page "/{Id:int?}"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm EditContext="this._editContext" OnSubmit=this.Submit>
    <InputText @bind-Value="@_data.Value" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int? Id { get; set; } = 0;
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private MyData _data = default!;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _data = new MyData() { Value = "First" };
        _editContext = new EditContext(_data);

        if (this.Id > 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            _data = new MyData() { Value = "Second" };
            _editContext = new EditContext(_data);
        }
    }

    private async Task Submit()
    {
        if (this.Id > 0)
            await Task.Delay(500);
        else
            await Task.Delay(500);
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually just swapped from using blazor for the project I was working on and never resolved the issue.